# CQWP does not return result for a specific query when filtering on a managed metadata field

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

We are facing a serious production issue. We've search the web extensively but to no avail.

Problem:

CQWP does not return result for a specific query when filtering on a managed metadata field.

ULS log:

The Uls logs provides 3 different messages that I could relate to every time the query is executed. The last item(level Medium) is displayed 14 times. For readability I've moved the ULS logs to the bottom of this question.

Query:

The query is as follows:

(I've translated this from dutch so pardon any typo's)

- Query: (top selection) Display items from all sites in the site collection
- ListType: Documentlibrary
- Contenttype:

  - Items from this group:Custom Document Contenttypes
  - Items from this content type: Verklaring
- Filter: Soort is equal to X
- extra info: the field soort (Type) is a managed metadata field that was assigned the value X

Managed Metadata Structure:

```
-managed metadata service
  -Contoso
    -Enterprise Taxonomy (term set)
      -Document (term)
        -Verklaring (term)
          -Soort (term)
            -x (term)
```

EXTRA INFO:

When I modify the filter to filter on Title the CQWP DOES return the correct document!
When I modify the query settings to search a specific library the CWQP also does return the correct document! (In this case I am filtering on a managed metadata field).

QUESTION:
Why doesn't the CQWP return the document when filtering on a managed metadata field over the entire site collection.
Why does the CQWP return the document when filtering on a managed metadata field over a single library.

(The type of information the CQWP should return (Soort:x) is stored in a dozen document libraries!)

Here are the ULS logs.

> Product: Web Content Management Category Publishing Level:
>   Monitorable:
>
> CrossListQueryCache::GetSiteData() caught exception
>   (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Kan deze actie niet voltooien. 
>   Probeer het opnieuw. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80004005): Kan deze actie niet voltooien.  Probeer het opnieuw.
>   bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CrossListQuery(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)     --- Einde van
>   intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   bij Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery query)     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.GetSiteData(SPWeb web,
>   SPSiteDataQuery siteDataQuery, Boolean useSpQueryOnList)     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.GetCrossListQueryResults(SPSiteDataQuery
>   query, SPWeb currentContext, Boolean onlyPopulateCache, Boolean
>   useSpQueryOnList, Int32 lcid)     bij
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CrossListQueryCache.GetSiteDataResults(CachedArea
>   cachedArea, SPWeb web, SPSiteDataQuery query, Boolean
>   useSpQueryOnList)) for query:  '450x010100C5FEE83B67FA6445B0C14AE8B7761BB8011E783' at url: /.
>   Titel webonderdeel: Inhoudsquery
>
> Product: Web Content Management Category Publishing Level: Warning
>
> Error occured while processing a Content Query Web Part. Performing
>   the following query '450x010100C5FEE83B67FA6445B0C14AE8B7761BB8011E783' generated the
>   following error: Kan deze actie niet voltooien.  Probeer het opnieuw.
>   at the following url: /. Titel webonderdeel: Inhoudsquery
>
> Kan deze actie niet voltooien. Probeer het opnieuw. This is Dutch. It
>   means something like: Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
>
> Product: Web Content Management Category Publishing Level: Medium
>   (this message is displayed 14 times)

EDIT: This does not happen when we query on 1 specific list.